# Is the Hessian matrix reported by MATLAB fmincon, fminunc the average Hessian Matrix?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

Both fmincon and fminunc report a hessian matrix. I could not find in the documentation about how is the hessian calculated. Is it the average hessian of all sample data point?

Answer (score 0):

The returned Hessian will typically correspond to either the last, or next-to-last, iterate ("point") prior to termination.  Several details come into play though (BFGS approximation? User supplied Hessian evalutation?, etc.), but all that is nicely summarized in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/hessian.html).